# how to change woocommerce mini cart button name to specific tag on header?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change mini "cart" button name to "view Cart" in header widget, i have tried on google but not yet get. 
 Change WooCommerce  "cart" button text for specific tag

Answer (score 3):

Add the following code to your function.php file, and change your specific tag

```
add_filter('gettext', 'translate_text'); 
add_filter('ngettext', 'translate_text');

function translate_text($translated) { 
$translated = str_ireplace('Order Total', 'New Text Goes Here', $translated); 
return $translated; 
}
```